# Create button with two functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded some code that uses the CodeIgniter framework, and I have the confirm now button which confirms the appointment. I would like to add the following code to the button so that it will confirm my appointment as well as take the user to the payment gateway.

Payment gateway code:

```
 <a href="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process?cmd=_paynow&amp;receiver=10907075&amp;item_name=Tutor+Session&amp;item_description=Tutor+Meetup&amp;amount=170.00&amp;return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lectiotutoring.co.za&amp;cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lectiotutoring.co.za"><img src="https://www.payfast.co.za/images/buttons/light-small-paynow.png" 
    width="165" 
    height="36" 
    alt="Pay" 
    title="Pay Now with PayFast" />
 </a>
```

Existing button with function i want to add the above code to:

```
 <form id="book-appointment-form" style="display:inline-block" method="post">
        <button id="book-appointment-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <?= !$manage_mode ? lang('confirm') : lang('update') ?>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_data" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not so much the button but rather the logic you put on the event. 
you first should validate success of appointment confirmation. If success is true, then you can redirect to payment gateway.
you can do this two ways from php side using header 301  or with ajax and javascript